# How to get data from MySql using javascript in leaflet

Tags: javascript, mysql, leaflet

I have Some tables in MqSql database.
I have to Fetch data from mysql table using javascript & show it in map of leaflet.
Can any any one tell me that how can I fetch data from mqsql using javascript ?

Comment: You should call Database connection from server side, so if you want specific data to be available for javascript then you can use `JSON`. Get values in severside and encode it to JSON and convert `JSON` object oriented and do awesome work

Answer (score 4):

Calling a MySQL database directly from the client is not an option, you'll need some sort of server side API.

If you insist on using JavaScript (on the server), Node.js is a valuable option.